# Logic Error within my Java program

Tags: java

I am just slowly learning Java and I am having problems with one of the exercises. The program is to take a user input of any amount of minutes (I am using the example 1000000000) and the program will then find the total number of years and days left. For some reason I am able to get the correct number of years at 19, but my logic on the last statement is not right and I am not getting 214 days.

Below is my code for the program and if you can make me understand why I am not seeing the correct answer please let me know. Also, I don't know if the book is mistaken, but the actual number of years it shows is 1902, but getting 1902 years is kind of impossible given only 1 billion minutes. That was a confusion as well. Thanks for all the replies in advance.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumberOFYears 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        //Create a Scanner object
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Prompt user for input
        System.out.print("Please enter number of minutes:");
        int totalMinutes = input.nextInt();

        //Find the number of hours
        int totalHours = totalMinutes / 60;

        //Find the number of days
        int totalDays = totalHours / 24;

        //Find the number of years
        int totalYears = totalDays / 365;

        //Find the number of days left 
        int remainingDays = totalHours % 24;
        System.out.println(remainingDays);

    }
}
```

Comment: The number of years and days left... until what?

Comment: btw, you only have 10 million minutes, not 1 billion

Comment: @MattBall sorry for not clarifying better. For 1 billion minutes how many Years and days is that?

Comment: @JoeySalacHipolito Sorry I mistyped the number of zeros.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calculating remaining days, so use this:

```
int remainingDays = totalDays % 365;
```

Answer (score 3):

Once you know the whole number of years, you compute the remaining days as

```
remainingDays = totalDays - 365 * totalYears;
```

You could also use the modulo operator. Of course your simple code ignores leap years…

Incidentally, `1,000,000,000 / (60 * 24 * 365)` is indeed `1902`,  and

```
1,000,000,000 / (60 * 24) - 365 * 1902 = 214
```

Comment: Yes this was a very basic exercise. Maybe the reason for getting 19 instead of 1902 was because I was inputting the wrong number of zeros. Thank you @Floris for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use

```
int remainingDays = totalDays%365;
```

instead. % is the modulus operator which returns a remainder smaller than the right operand